# Prolog if-statement

Tags: if-statement, prolog

I'm trying to implement a predicate that works as follows:

```
pred :-
   % do this always

   % if-statement
      %do this only, when if-statement is true

   % do this also always, independent if if-statement where true or false.
```

I need this functionality for a program, which has optionality a gui (XPCE) or not. You can call it with

```
start(true) % with gui
```

or

```
start(false) % without gui
```

Because I don't want to write two different predicates with the same logic, but one time with gui and another time without, I want to have one one predicate, that invokes the gui-code only if start(true) were invoked.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Prolog "if-statement" is:

```
(If -> Then; Else)
```

where `If`, `Then`, and `Else` are goals. You can use if easily on the definition of your predicate to switch on the argument of the predicate `start/1`:

```
pred :-
    % common code
    (   start(true) ->
        % gui-only code
    ;   % non-gui code
    ),
    % common code
```

When there's no `Else` goal, you can replace it with the goal `true`. The goal `(If -> Then)` fails when the `If` goal fails. I.e. the `(If -> Then)` goal is equivalent to `(If -> Then; fail)`, not to `(If -> Then; true)`.

Comment: Thx for your help! Yes, I know this syntax. But what can I do, if I don't have "% non guy code", like <common code> (If -> Then) <common code>.

Comment: Thanks Carlo. I have edit my answer to better clarify the semantics of this control construct.